# Django Interview Question for showing the result in coding

Tags: python, django

While showing my project by sharing the screen, I explained my project which is on Student Management System to interviewer but he was kept asking me about show me the result in code. I'm fresher and I haven't used python Django much so can anyone explain me what result should I show to the interviewer? I have done that project by watching tutorials on Student Management System. What do they expect us to show? YouTube Link - https://youtu.be/FMPpaTFdL2k

I explained him the overall working of code. I showed him backend admin panal and also python code fies urls settings models views. But he was keep repeating show me the result. Please explain me someone how can I show the result.

Comment: You might want to ask the interviewer to specify what they mean with "result in code".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not directly about programming but rather about feedback from an assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Suggesting two options

- Deploy your code to any free hosting platform to showcase your work. [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) is quite easy for deployment.
- create a git account and check-in the code in github. [github](https://github.com/) is one of most famous code management tool, widely used in industry. It also git addition in your profile, if you know basic of github